# How to send Texture2D over the Network in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d, photon

So, I have a game, where players, have to draw on `Texture2D` and I need to send that `Texture2D` for other players, but `onPhotonSerializeView` isn't working for that, because `Exception: cannot serialize(): UnityEngine.Texture2D`.

I found [this solution](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/10106/serialize-image) on site, but I don't really understand it, so maybe somebody could help.

My code:

```
private Texture2D DrawingSection;

private void Awake()
{
    DrawingSection = GameObject.Find("Canvas/pan_Background/pan_DrawingSection").GetComponent<Texture2D>();
}

private void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.isWriting)
    {
        if (photonView.isMine)
        {
           stream.SendNext(DrawingSection);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DrawingSection = (Texture2D)stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cant send `Texture2D`, you will need to transform it into a `byte[]` by doing

```
var bytes = DrawingSection.EncodeToPNG();
```

and then send the bytes like

```
stream.SendNext(bytes);
```

When reading the bytes, you would receve a `byte[]`

```
var bytes = (byte[])stream.ReceiveNext();
```

Then you need to parse the `byte[]` into a the `Texture2D`

This should probably work, i assume both sides have the same `TextureFormat` and size?

```
DrawingSection.LoadImage(bytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried your solution and I get crash when I call ```DrawingSection.LoadImage(bytes);```.

Comment: Ok, what does the log say?
Is the texture on both sides the same size and TextureFormat?

Comment: Yes, the size and TextureFormat are the same on both ends and error I get is:
We will now try to find a fix for the crash. Please wait...
Status: There is no fix available. Please report a bug.